# html2canvas export a4 size regardless of window size

Tags: angular, jspdf, html2canvas

I am using jspdf and html2canvas within an Angular 11 project. I have a 'dashboard' page which needs to have a 'print to pdf' function. This will take a snapshot of the current dashboard and export as a pdf file.

The problem I am having is: When the window is at full screen on a 1920px x 1280px display, it prints a full size pdf as intended. However if I resize the window to be smaller, the exported pdf shows a much smaller image on the output page. The same happens if the window is enlarged, the image scales outside of the page bounds. It appears to be ignoring my width/height/windowWidth/windowHeight options.

I was under the impression that the code I have written should create a new canvas with the dimensions I have set, and then export to a pdf. So window size shouldn't impact it at all.

What might I be doing wrong - or need to change - to make it always export a 1920x1280 image to the A4 page regardless of the size of the browser window?

```
captureScreen() {
 var data = document.getElementById('panel'); 
 var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
 canvas.width = 1920;
 canvas.height = 1280;

 var options = {
   canvas: canvas,
   scale: 1,
   width: 1920,
   height: 1280,
   windowHeight: 1280,
   windowWidth: 1920,
 };
 html2canvas(data, options).then((canvas) => {
   const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
   var pdf = new jspdf('l', 'mm', 'a4'); 

   var width = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
   var height = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();

   pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 1, 1, width, height);
   pdf.save(this.jobName + ' - Dashboard'); 
 });
 }
}
```

note 'panel' is the source canvas, 'canvas' is the pseudo-canvas I'm trying to generate

Comment: Have you tried not to set the image/screen size to static, but to get it via, for example, documentElement.clientWidth?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this can help. I used some code I found here elsewhere and a ratio to get the size right, then some offsets to make it centered on the page.

```
function saveAsPDF() {
        html2canvas($('div.panel.panel-default'), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var wid;
                var hgt;
                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", wid = canvas.width, hgt = canvas
                .height); //image data of canvas
                var hratio = hgt / wid;
                var doc = new jsPDF({
                    orientation: "landscape"
                });
                var width = doc.internal.pageSize.width;
                var height = doc.internal.pageSize.height;
                var height = width * hratio;
                doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', width*.025, 20, width*.95, height*.95);
                doc.save('AssetComparison.pdf');
            }
        });
    }
```